# CRTP - visibility of the type of a nested leaf class

Tags: c++, inner-classes, forward-declaration, crtp

I would like to understand if it is possible to use a nested class of a leaf CRTP class in the base CRTP class. The example below demonstrates the problem.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class A
{

protected:
    T* asLeaf(void)
        {return static_cast<T*>(this);}
    T const* asLeaf(void) const
        {return static_cast<T const*>(this);}
public:

    struct Inner
    {int a = 10;};

    void dispInner(void) const
        {std::cout << asLeaf()->inner.a << std::endl;}

    // I would like to use T::Inner in this class, e.g.
    // typename T::Inner mvInnerA;
    // However, I understand that it is not possible to
    // use it in the form that is stated above. Thus, 
    // I am looking for any possible workarounds. 

};


class B: public A<B>
{
public:
    struct Inner: public A<B>::Inner
    {int b = 20;};

protected:
    friend A<B>;
    B::Inner inner;

public:
    void dispInner(void) const
        {
            A<B>::dispInner();
            std::cout << asLeaf()->inner.b << std::endl;
        }
};


int main()
{

    B b;
    b.dispInner();

    return 0;

}
```

---

EDIT

I would like to provide several further comments based on the feedback that I have received:

- I am aware that I may not be using adequate design practices. In particular, it may be questioned whether `A` should be aware of the existence of `inner`. However, I would like to define an object `inner` of the type `B::Inner` in `A` instead of providing the definition of `inner` in `B` and using it in `A`.
- I am aware that I cannot forward declare `B` and/or `B::Inner` and of the reasons why this cannot be done. Thus, technically, the design problem does not have a solution. However, I am looking for a feasible workaround.

I have already considered several alternative solutions:

- One of the possible feasible solutions is not to make attempts to 'define' `B::Inner inner` in `A` and use the member functions of `A` to provide the functionality that allows to modify the `A<B>::Inner` part of `B::Inner inner`.
- Another possible solution is to define the classes `A<B>::Inner` and `B::Inner` explicitly (i.e. not as nested classes). However, I would prefer to avoid this, because, by design, it is not expected that any classes that do not derive from `A` will need to interact with `A<B>::Inner` or the classes that derive from `A<B>::Inner`

Both solutions that I have presented may be acceptable. However, I am looking for any feasible alternatives.

Comment: The general rule is that your Base class should not know about its child, you are introducing cyclic dependencies which is bad

Comment: @lapinozz that's why he's using the CRTP (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) and nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @lapinozz - You are thinking in terms of dynamic polymorphism, which is completely orthogonal to static polymorphism with the CRTP. The same "rules" don't necessarily apply.

Comment: I see, my bad, but then what is the problem? The commented code seems fine, what is the error?

Comment: @lapinozz Thank you for your comment. I believe that what you have stated in response to the original specification of my question is correct. However, please see the comments that I have made at the end of the question.

Comment: @StoryTeller I have to admit that I partially agree with lapinozz - the code in the definition of the question may contain poor design practices. I believe that, even in the context of CRTP, the class `A` should not be aware of the existence of the member variable `inner` of the class `B`. However, effectively, I am asking if it is possible to 'define' the member variable `inner` in `A`. Also, please see further comments that I have provided at the end of the question.

Comment: @user1391279 - There are sophisticated libraries that use the CRTP like this to provide deriving classes "hooks" for customization. You may deem your code as "poorly designed" for whatever reason, but to deem the entire idiom "poor design" is mighty arrogant.

Comment: Are you just looking for a convenient way to refer to the type inside your functions, instead of `typename T::Inner`?

Comment: @StoryTeller Thank you for the explanation. I have to admit that I have never seen CRTP used to gain direct access of the member variables of the leaf classes. I believe that it may be more conservative to avoid the designs that use this pattern. It 'feels' like, somehow, it is better to enforce the awareness of the existence of the member variable with a given name. Of course, I should have used the word 'uncommon' or the word 'non-conservative' instead of the word 'poor' and clearly stated that the comment is based on an opinion.

Comment: @StoryTeller A feasible alternative is not to define `inner` in `A` and use member functions of `A` to modify `inner`. However, I already know of several ways how this can be achieved (for example, member function templates or the solution that is stated in the answer). Thus, I am primarily looking for a plausible way to 'define' `T::Inner inner` in `A`. Of course, any other ideas will also be highly appreciated.

Comment: So you want to define a member that depends on `B`? Not just refer to the type `B::Inner` in `A`'s members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard say that:

> A class is considered a completely-defined object type (or complete type) at the closing `}` of the class-specifier.

It follows that `B` isn't a completely-defined object when you specialize `A` as `A<B>`. Therefore you can't expect to be able to access its members or types or whatever from within the definition of `A` (even though you can call back the derived class from within the definition of a member method of `A`, that is perfectly legal instead other than the purpose of the CRTP idiom).
In other terms, when you do this:

```
typename T::Inner mvInnerA
```

You have no guarantees that `T` is a completely-defined object and that's why you get the error.

---

A few alternatives:

1. You can define `mvInnerType` as a function instead of as a type and use it as a factory to create objects of type `T::inner`:

   ```
   [static] auto mvInnerA() {
       return typename T::Inner{};
   }
   ```

   Use it either as:

   ```
   auto foo = A<B>::mvInnerA();
   ```

   Or:

   ```
   auto foo = obj.mvInnerA();
   ```

   The right form depends on the fact that you make it `static` or not.
   Note that you can still use the hidden type somehow, even if its name isn't accessible:

   ```
   using HiddenType = decltype(A<B>::mvInnerA());
   HiddenType foo = A<B>::mvInnerA();
   ```
2. You can define `mvInnerA` using a template a alias declaration like this:

   ```
   template<typename U = T>
   using mvInnerA = typename U::Inner;
   ```

   Then use it as:

   ```
   auto foo = A<B>::mvInnerA<>{};
   ```

   For the type `T` is (let me say) *indirectly used through `U`* only when `mvInnerA` is instantiated, you don't have the problem mentioned above. The price to pay for that is the presence of an annoying `<>` and the fact that one can pass a custom type to `mvInnerA`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I am aware of the reason why I get an error (please accept my apologies, I will make amendments to the definition of the question). However, I am looking for a workaround.

Comment: Oh, ok, from the question it seems that you expect it to work as it is. I didn't understand you were asking for an alternative approach. Sorry.

Comment: @user1391279 Before I edit the answer, would it work for you a solution like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2JcbrV65osH9BuFW)? In other terms, `mvInnerA` is no longer a type but a function the return type of which is `T::inner`. You can get it using `decltype` whenever you want or create instances of the type be means of that function.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will accept your proposal as a valid answer.

Comment: @user1391279 Given a couple of alternatives directly in the answer. Hope they work for you.

Comment: Thank you for providing the answer. I found your second idea especially useful.

Answer (score 0):

How you can use an inner type of a CRTP template parameter is severely limited.

There can be no use in the scope of the class template definition itself. When instantiating the template, it will require the type `B` to be fully defined, which like [skypjack points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44759519/817643), it isn't. You can however use it in contexts that aren't immediately instantiated with the class template, which is mostly the member functions of `A`.

And while you cannot have a type alias for `B::Inner`, you can have a type alias template

```
template<class C>
using Inner = typename C::Inner
```

Which `A`'s member functions can use to avoid the verbosity of `typename B::Inner` and instead use `Inner<B>`.

Comment: Thank you for your last comment and for your answer. Unfortunately, as I have already mentioned in the comments and in the definition of the question, I am aware that it is not possible to define the member variable `B::Inner inner` in `A` and why this cannot be done. However, I wanted to understand if there are any feasible workarounds that would allow me to use `B::Inner` in `A` that I have not yet considered myself.  Unfortunately, I have to admit that I have failed to provide an adequate statement of the problem.